# в строке символов расставить слова в порядке убывания их длины ASM TASM

Tags: ассемблер, masm

имеется код на MASM для решения данной задачи как сделать его для TASM помогите люди добрые

```
.MODEL TINY
;
CR          EQU   0Dh
LF          EQU   0Ah
MaxKBufLen  EQU   80                ; With CR terminator
MaxWordNum  EQU   MaxKBufLen/2      ; char + space -> word
;
KEYB_BUF STRUCT
dbMaxLen    DB    ?
dbCharNum   DB    ?
chBuf       DB    MaxKBufLen Dup(?)
KEYB_BUF ENDS
;
WORD_LEN_POS STRUCT
dbPos DB    ?
dbLen DB    ?
WORD_LEN_POS ENDS
;
.DATA
sdAppInfo   DB    "Arranges words in descending length", CR, LF, "$"
sdPrompt    DB    " enter string of words (empty string - exit)"
sdCrLf      DB    CR, LF, "$"
kbBuf LABEL KEYB_BUF
sWordLenPos EQU   kbBuf + Sizeof KEYB_BUF
chOutBuf    EQU   sWordLenPos + Sizeof WORD_LEN_POS * MaxWordNum
;
.CODE
      ORG   100h
START:
      LEA   DX, sdAppInfo
      CALL  showSd
STR_LOOP:
      LEA   DX, sdPrompt
      LEA   SI, kbBuf
      MOV   CL, MaxKBufLen
      CALL  inputSc
      JCXZ  EXIT
      LEA   DI, sWordLenPos
      CALL  sc2WordLenPosArray
      JCXZ  EXIT
      MOV   SI, DI
      CALL  sortDescWordArray
      MOV   BX, SI
      LEA   DI, chOutBuf
      LEA   SI, kbBuf + 2
      CALL  wordLenPosArray2Sd
      MOV   DX, DI
      CALL  showSd
      CALL  crLf
      JMP   STR_LOOP
EXIT:
      RET
;
wordLenPosArray2Sd PROC Uses AX BX CX DX DI SI
; Input: BX = array of word parameters structs
;        CX = array length in structs
;        DI = destination string buffer
;        SI = source string buffer
 ASSUME BX: Ptr WORD_LEN_POS
      XOR   DH, DH
makeloop:
      PUSH  CX
      PUSH  SI
      MOV   DL, [BX].dbPos
      ADD   SI, DX
      XOR   CH, CH
      MOV   CL, [BX].dbLen
      REP MOVSB
      MOV   AL, " "
      STOSB
      POP   SI
      POP   CX
      ADD   BX, Sizeof WORD_LEN_POS
      LOOP  makeloop
      DEC   DI
      MOV   AL, "$"
      STOSB
 ASSUME BX: Nothing
      RET
wordLenPosArray2Sd ENDP
;
sc2WordLenPosArray PROC Uses AX DX DI SI
; Input:  DI = word parameters structs array
;         SI = stringCR address
; Output: CX = number of words
 ASSUME DI: Ptr WORD_LEN_POS
      MOV   AX, SI
      XOR   DX, DX            ; Word counter
makeloop:
      CALL  getWord
      JCXZ  exit
      SUB   BX, AX
      MOV   [DI].dbPos, BL
      MOV   [DI].dbLen, CL
      ADD   DI, Sizeof WORD_LEN_POS
      INC   DX
      JMP   makeloop
exit:
      MOV   CX, DX
 ASSUME DI: Nothing
      RET
sc2WordLenPosArray ENDP
;
getWord PROC Uses AX
; Input:  SI = stringCR address
; Output: BX = word address
;         CX = word length
;         SI = current position in stringCR
      XOR   CX, CX      ; Word length
skipspace:
      LODSB
      CMP   AL, CR
      JE    exit
      CMP   AL, "0"
      JL    skipspace
      CMP   AL, "9"
      JLE   itsword
      CMP   AL, "A"
      JL    skipspace
itsword:
      DEC   SI
      MOV   BX, SI
searchwordterm:
      LODSB
      CMP   AL, CR
      JE    wordfound
      CMP   AL, "0"
      JL    wordfound
      CMP   AL, "9"
      JLE   nextchar
      CMP   AL, "A"
      JL    wordfound
nextchar:
      INC   CX
      JMP   searchwordterm
wordfound:
      DEC   SI
exit:
      RET
getWord ENDP
;
sortDescWordArray PROC Uses AX CX DX DI SI
; Input: SI = array address
;        CX = array length in words
      MOV   DI, SI
sortloop:
      MOV   SI, DI
      ADD   SI, CX
      ADD   SI, CX
      MOV   AX, [DI]
cmploop:
      SUB   SI, 2
      CMP   [SI], AX
      JBE   nextword
      XCHG  [SI], AX
nextword:
      CMP   SI, DI
      JNZ   cmploop
      STOSW
      LOOP  sortloop
      RET
sortDescWordArray ENDP
;
inputSc PROC Uses DX
; Input:  DX = message address
;         SI = keyboard buffer address
;         CL = buffer length
; Output: CX = number of chars
;         SI = string address
 ASSUME SI: Ptr KEYB_BUF
      MOV   [SI].dbMaxLen, CL
      CALL  showSd
      MOV   DX, SI
      MOV   AH, 0Ah
      INT   21h
      CALL  crLf
      XOR   CH, CH
      MOV   CL, [SI].dbCharNum      ; String length
      LEA   SI, [SI].chBuf
 ASSUME SI: Nothing
      RET
inputSc ENDP
;
crLf PROC Uses DX
      LEA   DX, sdCrLf
      CALL showSd
      RET
crLf ENDP
;
showSd PROC Uses AX
; Input: DX = string address
      MOV   AH, 9
      INT   21h
      RET
showSd ENDP
;
      END   START
;
```

Comment: На этом сайте не решают чужие задачи и не пишут код за других.

Answer (score 3):

Ситуация эта интересна тем, что, несмотря на внешнюю похожесть, TASM использует совсем другие конструкции. В результате при попытке прогнать через него этот исходник мы получаем зашкаливающее количество сообщений об ошибках, с которыми и непонятно что делать. Это всё равно как паскалевский исходник прогонять через сишный компилятор - мозг задымится от попыток разобрать диагностику :) Поэтому для начала предлагаю избавиться от информационного мусора. Для этого:

1. Замените все `Uses` на явные `push/pop` нужных регистров, на входе и на выходе процедур соответственно.
2. Замените `ASSUME` на явную инициализацию: `ASSUME DI: Ptr WORD_LEN_POS` => `lea di, WORD_LEN_POS` и т.д. (и следующий пункт напрямую относится к этому тоже)
3. `STRUCT` => `STRUC`. И помните, что в TASM эта конструкция объявляет лишь тип данных, а не переменную этого типа, которую нужно создавать отдельно.
4. Проверьте дублирующиеся метки, их быть не должно (в TASM все метки глобальные, а локальные создаются отдельными конструкциями, но сейчас речь не об этом).
5. Конструкции SIZEOF в TASM нет, длина чего-либо вычисляется так:

   some_variable  db 0
   some_var_size EQU $ - some_variable

Ну, в принципе, и всё. После того, как всё это проделаете, количество ошибок сократится до нескольких единиц (а у меня так вообще до 0), что уже то что было в начале. И их текст можно будет прочитать, понять, и соотнести с тем, что вы найдёте в любом справочнике по TASM.

Comment: а можно ли без STRUC обойтись

Comment: и что означает       MOV   CL, [BX].dbLen    ----->  .dbLen тобишь смещение по этому адресу?

Comment: КАК ЭТОТ КОД СДЕЛАТЬ ПОД 8086

Comment: Это и есть код под 8086.

Comment: а можно ли без STRUC обойтись